# Animating a rotation but with acceleration

Tags: animation, modifiers, graph-editor

I am working on an animation where a wheel is rotating. This has been done using the 'cycles' modifier on an F-Curve. Now I want it to slowly start up a few seconds into the video, and from frame X on, it should rotate at constant speed.

Adding the accelerating animation is quite simply done by inserting a keyframe before the rotation and adjusting the graph accordingly. However, the cycles modifier insists on repeating the acceleration part of the curve, too. In my case, I need the modifier to only repeat the constant rotation. I have not found a way to restrict the keyframes that should be repeated with the 'restrict frame range' settings. Can this be done and I just haven't seen it?

After inserting acceleration:
[image: After inserting acceleration]

Expected graph (edited):
[image: Expected graph (edited)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the cycles modifier can't be set to repeat only a certain part of the action. You have two alternatives.

#### Linear Extrapolation

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and choose **Linear Extrapolation**. This way the wheel will keep rotating based on the last two keyframes up to infinity.
[image: linear extrapolation]

#### Use Non Linear Animation

Go to the NLA editor. Press the down button. The active action will be converted to an action strip. I have duplicated the action strip with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and moved it to the frame, where the original strip ends.
[image]

With the second strip selected, we can set it to the original action, if a duplicate action was made, although this is not necessary.
Set the *Start Frame* to your second keyframe, frame which one one the wheels rotation has reached its final speed. Set the *End Frame* to the last keyframe. Set the repeat scale as desired.
[image]
This way the linear motion of the action is isolated and repeated.

Comment: I used the first solution, which is of course only useful for rotations.
I am glad you mentioned the second one though. I have not yet worked with the NLA editor at all, but good to know that you can do such stuff there.
Thanks for the help!